# Minimize Employee Idle Time for Ordered Tasks Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, optimization, schedule, np

Suppose there is a product to be manufactured in a factory, requiring `o` operations from start to finish. Each operation takes time `t_o` to complete. There is at least one employee for each operation, and no employee can do more than one operation. However, each operation can be performed by at most 2 employees (so the total number of employees is capped at `2*o`).

The goal is to allocate the correct number of employees for each operation (1 or 2 employees) such that we minimize the average WAITING TIME per employee.

For example:
There are 2 operations, taking 1.0 and 0.5 mins respectively.

Case 1: 1 employee performs operation 1 (let's call this `o1`), and 1 employee performs `o2`. Then, the total waiting time for the production line is 0.5 mins (because the second employee is idle for 0.5 mins each time), and the average waiting time per employee is 0.5/2 = 0.25

Case 2: 2 employees perform `o1`, 1 employee performs `o2`. Then, the total waiting time is 0 mins because in 1 minute, both operations can be completed twice. Hence the average waiting time per employee is 0/3 = 0

Case 3: 1 employee performs `o1`, 2 employees perform `o2`. Then, the total waiting time is 1.5 mins, because in 1 minute, `o1` is completed once and `o2` is completed by a single employee in 0.5 mins (so the first `o2` employee is idle for 0.5 mins, and the second `o2` employee is ideal for the whole 1 minute). Hence the average waiting time per employee is 1.5/3 = 0.5

Here, we pick CASE 2, because it minimizes the average waiting time per employee (0 min/employee).

I am currently using a greedy approach where I start by assigning just one employee per operation. Then I am iterating through the list of operations and increasing the number of employees for the operation that CAUSES the highest waiting time. I am not sure how good of an approximation this is, but I am looking for a close-to-optimal solution.

I've looked at task-scheduling algorithms and the Hungarian algorithm, but I'm having trouble applying any of these examples to my problem.

Comment: I don't understand your specification. In Case 2, why is `o2` performed twice, when it's only necessary to perform it once in Case 1? Similarly, in Case 3, why is the second employee idle throughout, when in Case 2 they also performed the operation? Just going by the numbers, it looks like you're aiming at the constraints that all operations should be completed exactly once, and that if two employees are working on the same operation, the time to completion for that operation is halved. Is this an accurate representation of your problem?

Comment: @fuglede - there is no cap on the no. of times each op is performed. Case 1: for every minute that this manufacturing line is running, both ops are done once each and the total wait time is 0.5 mins because the 2nd employee is idle for the next 0.5 mins after finishing his work in the first 0.5 mins (let's assume production is under way and ignore latency). Case 3: for every minute that the line is running, op1 gets completed only once, and op2 CAN ONLY get completed once because even though there are more employees, there is only ONE product being passed on from op1 to op2 in that 1 minute.

Comment: I think your heuristic is optimal. Consider p1,p2,p3 the number of people you assigned to o1, o2, o3.
The waiting time to complete n pieces is T.
Say arbitrarily that you need T because of o1 (the slowest).

You can add another person.
Two cases: 
- you add to p1
at most, you will compete n pieces twice faster, and hence will wait at most T/2. The total awaiting time added is then at most T (two people waiting T/2).

- you add to p2.
You can not do more than n pieces in T, so you add T to the total waiting time

You can stop adding people when the slowest o has already two people